# Solving $f(x)f(y)= 8$ and $g(x)g(y)=4$, where $f(x) = a^x + a^{-x}$ and $g(x) = a^x - a^{-x}$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

> There are two real functions $f$ and $g$ for $ x, y> 0, a >1$ such that $f(x) = a^x + a^{-x}$ and $g(x) = a^x - a^{-x}$.
>
> Find the $x$ satisfying $f(x)f(y)= 8$ and $g(x)g(y)=4$.

I've tried this by putting the $X$ and $Y$ as instead of the $ a^x$ and $a^y$ respectively. But the calculatuion process really complicated. Is there any efficient way?

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Show us what you did.

Comment: How is $y$ defined?

Comment: I eidted my post @Wuestenfux

Comment: @ParclyTaxel the $y$ is also positive real number like the $x $. I edited my question.

Comment: Idea: $f(x)g(x) = (a^x + a^{-x})(a^x - a^{-x}) = a^{2x} - a^{-2x} = g(2x)$. Therefore, $f(x)f(y)g(x)g(y) = \ldots $

Comment: You might notice that your equation $X^2+Y^2=2XY$ has a consequence which may help a lot.

Comment: @MarkBennet, I haven't notice at all. Thanks. Plus thanks for the Matti tell me different approach.

Comment: It would be nice if you could post your final answer.

Comment: Yes I'm solving now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will get the system
$$a^{x+y}+\frac{1}{a^{x+y}}+a^{x-y}+\frac{1}{a^{x-y}}=8$$ and
$$a^{x+y}+\frac{1}{a^{x+y}}-a^{x-y}-\frac{1}{a^{x-y}}=4$$
Now substitute.
For intstance
$$u+\frac{1}{u}+v+\frac{1}{v}=8$$
$$u+\frac{1}{u}-\left(v+\frac{1}{v}\right)=4$$

Answer (score 1):

Speacial thanks for the Mark bennet.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Notice that

$$f(x)=2\cosh(x\log a),\\g(x)=2\sinh(x\log a).$$

Then

$$f(x)f(y)-g(x)g(y)=4\cosh((x-y)\log a)=4$$

so that $$x=y.$$

Also

$$f(x)f(y)+g(x)g(y)=4\cosh((x+y)\log a)=12$$ so that

$$x=y=\frac{\text{arcosh }3}{2\log a}=\log_a\sqrt{3+2\sqrt2}=\log_a(1+\sqrt2).$$